# Is it guaranteed the rest of a method will execute after WhenAll if used on shutdown?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, service, async-await

I have a dispatcher object that handles the starting up and shutting down of tasks as requests come in to my service through a pipe.

My on stop method looks like this:

```
        protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {
            Task t = CalculationServiceProcess.Instance.Shutdown();
            t.Wait();
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            foreach (Exception e in ae.InnerExceptions)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

My Instance.Shutdown Method is as follows:

```
    public Task Shutdown()
    {
        _shutdownTokenSource.Cancel();
        Task t = _dispatcher.Shutdown();
        _shutdownTokenSource.Dispose();
        ///some more code
        return t;
    }
```

And the dispatchers shutdown method looks like:

```
      public Task Shutdown()
    {
        Task t = Task.WhenAll(_dispatchedItems.Select((item => item.Value.Task)).ToArray());
        _dispatchedItems.Clear();
        return t;
    }
```

What I am wondering is will the dispose method be called and will the "//some more code" be guaranteed to run? Or when the WhenAll task finishes, will my t.Wait() method return and OnStop finish executing, and the service shut down before that code executes?

Comment: Can you post some documentation to the "Instance.Shutdown" method. That would help.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin The method is shown in the question.

Comment: I don't see anything why it must not behave like you want. What makes you suspect it wouldn't behave correctly?